# how resolve this error TypeError: <function domain_users at 0x7f836efb1aa0> is not JSON serializable

Tags: odoo-8

my code:
     def domain_users(self):
        userx=self.env.user.login
        if self:
            at=[]
            userx = self.env.user.login
            if userx == "login.user":
               ids_biens=self.env['gmat.journaleline'].search([('exp_P','>',0),('rapJor_ids','=',self.id)])
                print'--------liste id----------',ids_biens.bien_id.id
                for item in ids_biens:
                    at.append(item.bien_id.id)
                a=tuple(at)
                print a
                return a 
            else:
                ids_biens=self.env['gmat.journaleline'].search([('rapJor_ids','=',self.id)])
                print'--------liste id----------',ids_biens.bien_id
                for item in ids_biens:
                    at.append(item.bien_id.id)
                a=tuple(at)
                print a
                return a
user_filter = fields.Many2one('gmat.nbien',domain=['id','in',domain_users])